# How to kill multiple process list using command in linux for DB2

Tags: linux, mysql, db2

I connected mysql in linux server using `mysql -u root -p dbnmae` then i use cmd `show processlist;` and its showing result like

```
+---------+------+
| Id      | User |
+---------+------+
| 123     | root |
| 1234    | root |
| 1235    | root |
| 1236    | root |
| 1004    | root |
| 1205    | root |
| 1216    | root |
```

Now I want to kill some process_id (1234,1005,1205) using one command only. When I tried to kill in many ways but its not working properly. Its showing error like a

```
mysql> kill 1234 1005 1205;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1205' at line 1
```

Can you please help me to how to solve this issue. This is a DB2 server.

Comment: You say "DB2", but the program you use is `mysql` (which is most certainly *not* DB2).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Yes, I am using for DB2 only but its SQL server.
I got the solution for my question. We need to use a command like this: 
`Select concat ('kill ', ID,';') from information_schema. Processlist where TIME >= 3000 AND TIME <= 5000 AND INFO like 'Select COUNT (*) %' INTO OUTFILE 'kills2.csv';`
 And then open the .CSV file and copy all commands from .CSV file and paste into it. It will delete all kill id which is coming from CSV file.